# How can I curreclty crop/resize image in tableviewcells to fit properly

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, uiimage

I am trying to display set of images in table view cell. All the images are different size. I want to crop or resize images so as to look like in photos app. How can I achieve this.
Thanks,
Shakthi

    `cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.imageView.image = image;
    UIImageView * view=cell.imageView;`

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70 , 70);//not working
view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70 , 70);//not working
```

My result;

[image]

expecting
[image]
Photo application nicely changed every images to uniform size.

Comment: How are you adding it in tableView ? , post the related code.

Answer (score 1):

Use below to crop the image , you need to pass the crop rect.

```
CGImageRef myImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], myCropRect);
myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myImageRef ]]; 
CGImageRelease(myImageRef );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UIImage+Resizing` category from [NYXImagesUtilities](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesUtilities). Example:

```
UIImage* cropped = [myImage cropToSize:(CGSize){75, 75} usingMode:NYXCropModeCenter];
```

or [do it yourself](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/).